# How to shorten/clean a URL using UrlRewriterFilter on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, url, tomcat, url-rewriting

I am new to Tomcat URL shortening. I have installed `UrlRewriterFilter` for my web app but can't quite understand how to implement a new rule.

I have a link on a blogs index page linking to an individual blog post.

For example: `read-post.jsp?id=1&title=Some-blog-post-title`.

I would like the URL to be changed to `read-post/some-blog-post-title`.

This is what I have attempted that doesn't work:

```
<rule>
        <from>^read-post/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)</from>
        <to>read-post.jsp?id=$1&amp;title=$1</to>
</rule>
```

How can I achieve this in UrlreWriterFilter given that the URL's are dynamically generated although follow the same pattern?

Comment: You have two variables id and title in your example. But you want to use `read-post/some-blog-post-title`, so where is id?

Comment: I don't want id to be visible.

Comment: In your rule: `read-post.jsp?id=$1&amp;title=$1` here both id and title will be "some-blog-post-title". Is this what you want?

Comment: I mean `id` value is 1 in your example, but there is no value 1 in `read-post/some-blog-post-title`

Comment: Does it matter that I don't want the post id in the url? Or does it have to be in? Basically I want the user to just see `/read-post/some-blog-post-title` and not the post id. But if it has to be in there that's fine also.

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your rule definition, it should start with `/` as below.

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <from>^/read-post/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)</from>
        <to>/read-post.jsp?id=$1&amp;title=$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

`UrlRewriterFilter` starts processing after your context, so using `/` at the beginning means after your context.

When you use this rule, any request to `read-post.jsp?id=1&title=Some-blog-post-title` will be forwarded to `read-post.jsp` with `id=Some-blog-post-title` and `title=Some-blog-post-title` But `id` is useless here, if your `read-post.jsp` page can find post with just title it is ok, but if `read-post.jsp` requires an `id` to find post, then you should include `id` in url also like below.

```
  <urlrewrite>
        <rule>
            <from>^/read-post/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)</from>
            <to>/read-post.jsp?id=$1&amp;title=$2</to>
        </rule>
  </urlrewrite>
```

So, you can use URLs in this format `read-post/1/Some-Blog-Title` There will be an `id` in the url.

Comment: I applied that rule and it still uses original URL: `http://localhost:8080/site/read-post.jsp?id=1&title=some-cool-title-of-blog`.

Comment: What is in your web.xml file? Did you add settings for urlrewritefilter as in the documentation? Also set log level to debug for urlrewrite in web.xml and check the logs.